# Google cloud NLP integration with UiPath

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp, rpa

I am trying to integrate the google NLP (text Classification) with UiPath. But I am facing some problems, please let me know how can I do that.

Comment: Could you please let us know what are the problems you are facing? What are the Error messages you are seeing? What have you tried? Are you following a tutorial or documentation? Please add these details to your question so we'll know how to help you

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to craft input for Google NLP and inject them via API Call.
Then grab output from Google NLP for a result.

If you need more explanation please be more specific on your questions.